# Floating point inexact result exception in TFDTable Component in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am using TFDTable component in Delphi Seattle. I have kept this table component at design time.

While executing
TFDTable(Compo).Open

I get error while debugging (Ctrl +F7) "Floating point inexact result at 0042F353"

I googled, but got the reason but didn't get exactly what it is.

Any suggestions?

Reference URL:

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/e8/524771.html

> Floating Point inexact result
>
> This exception suggests that you have
> the "loss of precision" mask   bit in the FPU turned OFF.  It is
> normally ON.  Look for the $0020   bit in the system variable
> Default8087CW and try ORing in $0020 into   the control word with a
> Set8087CW(Default8087CW or $0020) statement.

[http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~resnik/ling645_sp2002/cmu_manual/node19.html](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Eresnik/ling645_sp2002/cmu_manual/node19.html)

Comment: What exactly is it that you do not get? Please, be more specific and copy - paste the relevant lines you want to refer to (keep the source link though). Without the relevant text here, your question might become worthless for future readers. IMO, the text I *believe* you refer to states clearly what it is about.

Comment: What driver are you using? What is the nature of the data that you're returning? Do you get that error for any table or just for a specific one? Have you tried opening a copy of that table but without any data? The problem may be the driver, an unsupported feature in the table you're attempting to open, or a value in the table that is processing incorrectly.

Comment: You need to show some real code in your q with sufficient detail to enable readers to reproduce your problem if you want any help. TFDTable(Compo).Open obviously isn't real code.

Comment: @MartynA: Sorry for delay in reply. There a table which has only less than 20 rows with one numeric column and there are other columns as well with other data type.

Comment: @Tom: I am not getting this point, "> then as "Floating Point inexact result  -> This exception suggests that you have the "loss of precision" mask
bit in the FPU turned OFF.  It is normally ON.  Look for the $0020
bit in the system variable Default8087CW and try ORing in $0020 into
the control word with a Set8087CW(Default8087CW or $0020) statement. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a well known issue that `Default8087CW` as a global variable can be misused by libraries or even your own code and be changed at any time in ways that cause unexpected results of FP calculations or unexpected exceptions to occur. The six lowest bits of the 8087 FPU `Control word` are the exception **mask** bits, meaning that if a bit is set, corresponding exception is **masked**, that is prevented from being raised.

The "loss of precision" mask bit that John Herbster is talking about is one of those bits, in Delphis `TArithmeticException` enum called `exPrecision`. Further he suggests to assure this bit is set by calling the `Set8087CW(Default8087CW or $0020)`. Since you are using Delphi 10 Seattle, it is recommended to use the `SetExceptionMask()` function (from the `System.Math` unit) instead, since it handles equally also the corresponding SSE mask on 64 bit hw:

```
var
  OldExceptionMask: TArithmeticExceptionMask;
...
OldExceptionMask := SetExceptionMask(GetExceptionMask + [exPrecision]);
```

Calling the above before `TFDTable(Compo).Open` should solve your problem.

The function takes and returns a `TArithmeticExceptionMask` (set of `TArithmeticException`). All other exception enums and FPU/SSE related functions are in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Floating-Point_Number_Control_Routines).